# Did I actually gain anything here using tasks and async

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to get to grips with Tasks and the Async Await keywords. I have a little sample method which essentially invokes *n* number of methods. Two key points to note are

- I don't care about the order the methods run in
- All methods should be called on a background thread

With this here is the code.

```
public async void Handle<T>(T entry) {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        Parallel.ForEach(_handlers, pair => {
            pair.Value.Invoke(_reference, new object[] {
                entry
            });
        });
    });
```

My question is did I actually gain any async or parallelism out of the code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're running in a UI application, since parallel code on a server is quite rare.

In this case, wrapping parallel code in a `Task.Run` is perfectly normal, and a common pattern when you wish to execute parallel code asynchronously.

I would make a few changes:

1. Avoid `async void`. Return a `Task`, so you can handle errors more cleanly.
2. Follow the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern naming conventions (i.e.,
   end your method with `Async`).
3. Return the `Task` directly instead of `async`/`await` (if your entire `async` method is just to `await` a task, you can avoid some overhead just by returning the task directly).

Like this:

```
public Task HandleAsync<T>(T entry) {
    return Task.Run(() => {
        Parallel.ForEach(_handlers, pair => {
            pair.Value.Invoke(_reference, new object[] {
                entry
            });
        });
    });
```

I'd also consider two other possibilities:

1. <s>Consider using `Parallel.Invoke` instead of `Parallel.ForEach`. It seems to me that `Parallel.Invoke` is a closer match to what you're actually trying to do.</s> (See svick's comment below).
2. Consider leaving the parallel code in a synchronous method (e.g., `public void Handle<T>(T entry)`) and *calling* it with `Task.Run` (e.g., `await Task.Run(() => Handle(entry));`). If your `Handle[Async]` method is intended to be part of a general-purpose library, then you want to avoid the use of `Task.Run` within your asynchronous methods.

Comment: Thanks, your points actually cleared up my usage understanding a bit.

Comment: I think `Parallel.Invoke()` makes sense if you already have a collection of (parameter-less) `Action`s. That doesn't seem to be the case here, you would need something like `Parallel.Invoke(_handlers.Select(pair => new Action(() => pair.Value.Invoke(_reference, new object[] { entry }))).ToArray());`. That doesn't seem clearer to me.

Comment: @svick: I agree with you. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

No, you've gained nothing here. Even if you made it return `Task` (so that the caller could check when everything had finished) you'd be better off without async:

```
public Task Handle<T>(T entry)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_handlers, pair => 
        {
            pair.Value.Invoke(_reference, new object[] { entry });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was my suspicion. Is it correct to say this because the invoke is sync. Also is the parallel foreach of any value here?

Comment: @McDonnellDean: It's mostly because you're just using `Task.Run`

Comment: I don't follow, does that mean there is a way to make the above run async?

Comment: @McDonnellDean: It *is* running asynchronously already - but `Task.Run` puts whatever you give it into a separate thread anyway, so you're not getting the benefits of normal asynchrony.